# Escape double quote in perl

Tags: perl, escaping, double-quotes

When I passed a variable $local_ntwk_ao_vpn ("X0 Subnet") into a perl script, it only took "X0" and lost "Subnet" part. I tried to escape double-quotes as below, but still didn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Expect;
#Assume the first 20 args are OK
my $local_ntwk_ao_vpn    = $ARGV[20];   # <-----"X0 Subnet"

# Telnet into the remote firewall
my $expect = Expect->new();
$expect->spawn("telnet 10.100.100.100 6025");
$expect->send("\n");
sleep(3);
$expect->expect( 10, 'User:' );
$expect->send("aUser\n");
$expect->expect( 10, 'Password:' );
$expect->send("password\n");
$expect->expect( 5, '>' );

$expect->send("configure\n");
$expect->expect( 5, '#' );

$expect->send("vpn policy site-to-site TESTVPN\n");
$expect->expect( 5, '#' );
$expect->send("network local name \"$local_ntwk_ao_vpn\"\n");  # <-- Still doesn't work here.
$expect->expect( 5, '#' );
$expect->send("exit\n");
$expect->send("end\n");
$expect->soft_close();
```

---

Errorlog:

```
(edit-site-to-site[TESTVPN])# network local name "X0"
% Error encountered at '^' marker:
    network local name "X0"
                       ^^M
% Error: No matching command found.
(edit-site-to-site[TESTVPN])# exit
```

Desired command:

```
 (edit-site-to-site[TESTVPN])# network local name "X0 Subnet"
```

Comment: Note that if you don't quote the entire value when invoking this script, the shell will split the args on the space between them, and pass them in as two consecutive args.  If you do quote the value when invoking the script, the shell will leave the two words and the space between them as a single arg, stripping the quotes before Perl gets the value.  You need to quote the value you pass to the script, realizing that this is for the shell's benefit.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are mistaken about `$ARGV[20]` containing `X0 Subnet`. It appears to contain only `X0`.

Did you use

```
script.pl ... X0 Subnet ...
```

when you should have used

```
script.pl ... 'X0 Subnet' ...
```